# Are properties in Interfaces not data?

Tags: c#

It is not possible to have a instance variable or any implementation in an interface.  But we can have properties.  Are not properties just get and set methods?  And are get and set methods not just ways in which to get and set variables?  Is this not cheating?  As far as I can remember C++ and Java do not allow this.  It seems to be that there is something not so "pure" about the implementation of interfaces in C#.

Comment: Properties are and always were just syntactic sugar for calling a get and/or set method.

Comment: Properties, as you said, are just methods. The fact that they may or may not write to an underlying field is not a factor. Properties may in fact never do anything at all or not write to any field or retrieve data from any field. EDIT: Maybe the confusion comes from auto-properties. An auto-property has very similar syntax to interface properties. However, auto-properties are just syntax sugar to write to an underlying field; this isn't the case for interface properties.

Comment: Properties in interfaces are abstract functions. Nothing more.

Comment: Does C++ have properties? Does C++ have interfaces?

Comment: In an interface, what you see is NOT a property, it is NOTa method, it is just a definition of what the property, or the corresponding methods, must look like in any class that implements the interface.  This may sound subtle, but it is not. It is a massive distinction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are not properties just get and set methods?

Yes, they are. They're *methods*. Behaviour, not implementation details about how that behaviour is implemented. That's the difference between properties and fields - and that's why properties are allowed in interfaces.

> And are get and set methods not just ways in which to get and set variables?

No, they're methods. They can be implemented however you want. They *may* be implemented via simple fields - but they may not be. (Which field do you think `DateTime.Now` reads?)

> As far as I can remember C++ and Java do not allow this.

Java certainly allows you to put getter and setter methods on an interface...

Comment: ... and C++ doesn't even have interfaces!

Answer (score 4):

What you see in an interface is not a concrete property, it is just a *definition* of what the properties signature(the property name,  return type access modifier, and whether it has a get as well as a set, for example) ***must look like*** in any class that implements this interface.

In an interface, it is ***NOT*** a get and set method, it is not an actual method at all, it is just the definition of what the get and set method must look like in any class that implements this interface.

This may sound subtle, but it is not. It is a massive distinction.

I know that within an abstract class, we refer to things such as

```
 public abstract void Required(int a, string b);
```

as *abstract methods*.   This is semantics I guess, and nothing said here will change what is common accepted usage, but they are, (just like an interface definition), really just a specification and a requirement for the signature of the methods within the classes that derive from this abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

Properties are just two methods, packages as a single name. By defining a property in an interface (`Name` for example) you actually are defining two separate methods (`get_Name` and `set_Name`). You can define the methods (`get` and `set` accessors) however you want. Usually you return or set the value of a field, but this is not mandatory.

You can do the same in Java or C++ by defining two separate method (`getName` and `setName` for example).

Properties in interfaces, may seem like [C# auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), but they are really different. When you define an interface like this:

```
interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You are forcing the interface implementer to create a read/write property named `Name`, but when you do the same in a class:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

compiler automatically creates a backing-field to hold the a string value, and defines two method that read/write from/to that string field.

Answer (score 2):

Properties are just getters and setters, yes (you can confirm this by using `monodis` or `ildasm` an your executable, and see that they're just methods.

So properties in interfaces are just abstract functions. It doesn't matter whether you have a backing field or not. The backing field (variable belonging to that property), essentially, has nothing to do with the property itself.

So no, properties do not require memory, and are not data, their backing fields may be, but properties themselves are not data.